SVG Mask Effect only activating when hovering specific elements?
All the credits to Aceternity UI for the original code!
Hello,
I am trying change the code below to make the effect only activate when hovering specific elements.
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

export const MaskContainer = ({
  children,
  revealText,
  size = 10,
  revealSize = 600,
  className,
}: {
  children?: string | React.ReactNode;
  revealText?: string | React.ReactNode;
  size?: number;
  revealSize?: number;
  className?: string;
}) => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState<any>({ x: null, y: null });
  const containerRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const updateMousePosition = (e: any) => {
    const rect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setMousePosition({ x: e.clientX - rect.left, y: e.clientY - rect.top });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    containerRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePosition);
    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) {
        containerRef.current.removeEventListener(
          "mousemove",
          updateMousePosition
        );
      }
    };
  }, []);
  let maskSize = isHovered ? revealSize : size;

  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={containerRef}
      className={cn("h-screen relative", className)}
      animate={{
        backgroundColor: isHovered ? "var(--slate-900)" : "var(--white)",
      }}
    >
      <motion.div
        className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center text-6xl absolute bg-black bg-grid-white/[0.2] text-white [mask-image:url(/mask.svg)] [mask-size:40px] [mask-repeat:no-repeat]"
        animate={{
          maskPosition: `${mousePosition.x - maskSize / 2}px ${
            mousePosition.y - maskSize / 2
          }px`,
          maskSize: `${maskSize}px`,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 0,
        }}
      >
        <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black h-full w-full z-0 opacity-50" />
        <div
          onMouseEnter={() => {
            setIsHovered(true);
          }}
          onMouseLeave={() => {
            setIsHovered(false);
          }}
          className="max-w-4xl mx-auto text-center text-white  text-4xl font-bold relative z-20"
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </motion.div>

      <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center  text-white">
        {revealText}
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

Currently, as soon as the mouse cursor touches a container with text, regardless if its actually touching the text or not, it activates. As can be seen here (https://ui.aceternity.com/components/svg-mask-effect). If you move your pointer to one of the corners on the last row of text it will activate despite there being no text there.
I've been trying to change it so that it only activates when touching actual text and not the container containing text. It feels like I'm missing something simple but I can't make it out. Would love if someone could help me figure this out.
Thank you!
I'm using Next.js. The link above have the steps on how to install the component in your app.
